# Trouble with Angular Validation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, validation

I'm new to Angular and have trouble debugging my use of form validations. Namely I want to disable sumbit button if the form is invalid. My problem is that it stays invalid even if I've inserted apparently valid input. This goes so far as to be even invalid for empty form:

This is my template (original code is commented out):

```
<div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <a href ng-click="companiesCtrl.newEdit()" class="btn btn-primary">Uus asutus</a>
            <table class="table">
                <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="company in companiesCtrl.list">
                    <td><a href ng-click="companiesCtrl.load(company)">{{company.name}}</a></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <form id="editForm">
            <!--<form ng-show="companiesCtrl.showEdit()" ng-submit="companiesCtrl.save()" name="editForm">-->
                <!--<h4>Asutuse detailid</h4>-->
                <!--<a ng-show="companiesCtrl.edit.id != 0" class="btn btn-primary" ng-href="../{{companiesCtrl.edit.id}}/product/list">Asutuse vaatele</a>-->
                <!--<fieldset class="form-group">-->
                    <!--<input  ng-model="companiesCtrl.edit.id"/>-->
                <!--</fieldset>-->
                <!--<fieldset class="form-group">-->
                    <!--<input placeholder="Asutuse nimi" title="Asutuse nimi" ng-model="companiesCtrl.edit.name" ng-required="true"/>-->
                <!--</fieldset>-->
                <!--<fieldset class="form-group">-->
                    <!--<input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" ng-disabled="editForm.$invalid" value="Salvesta" />-->
                <!--</fieldset>-->
            </form>
            <span>{{editForm.$error}}</span>
            <span>{{editForm.$invalid}}</span>
            <span>{{editForm.$valid}}</span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and this is the result from the "span"-s:

```
{"required":[{}]} true false
```

My question is, as I'm new to Angular, how to debug this, or what are the additional factors  that can affect form "valid" status.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find the problem myself. I had multiple directives that were hidden by ng-show. All of them had a form named "editForm" this cause Angular to validate all the forms.

Just if someone ever needs this for debugging: I added following to my template:

```
<span ng-repeat="error in compForm.$error"><span ng-repeat="error2 in error">
                {{companiesCtrl.logThis(error2)}}</span></span>
```

and the following to my controller:

```
this.logThis = function(toLog) {
                console.log(toLog);
            }
```

From log I saw that it was validating too many times and quessed my problem.